# iTunes 12.7 how to download all music from iTunes Match

Tags: itunes, music, itunes-match

Mac OS 10.13.4, iTunes 12.7.4

Somehow my music library has become screwed up, and almost all of my 28,000-odd tracks aren't where they should be (according to iTunes). I can create a playlist of all the tracks, and I can export that playlist to a text file. But I don't see how to download those tracks to a library.

All of this happened following moving my Film library to an external drive, tho I don't see the connection. My TV Programs appear to be Ok.

Help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to download the already uploaded music to the iCloud (iTunes Match), you could try re-syncing the media library.

Step1 : sign out from iTunes 
Step 2 : Delete all the remaining music files.
Step 3 : Sign in to the iTunes.
Step 4 : Let it to sync the music library from iCloud.

For more info : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8046575

Comment: So do I have to tell it to sync or does that happen automatically

Comment: It will automatically happen after you have logged in to the iCloud using iTunes. However, to be on the safe side, you could try it in a different Mac or a PC.  If you have already backed up your Existing Music Library to a local drive , then no problem.  Go for it.

Comment: Seems to be working OK: downloading as I write. All albums appeared in iTunes, I selected them all, right click Download, and away it went. Good that I have an unlimited plan with my ISP . . .